# jQuery: Check if hash contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

I'm looking to try and check if the hash in the url contains a certain value before proceeding, I have a function that works like so:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash,
        number = $(hash).index(),
        width = 403,
        final = width * number;
        setTimeout(function () {
        $('.news-inner-wrap').animate({
            'marginLeft': "-=" + final + "px"
        });
        }, 1000);
});
```

So if the hash is `www.website.com/#news-item-03` it will slide the user horizontally along to the 3rd news story, this works great!. I only want this function to fire though if the hash contains `news-item` obviously the number after each will change, but if the hash begins with `news-item` then I want the function above to be fired, I'm not even sure it this is at all possible, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for jQuery, this should work nicely

```
 if (window.location.hash) {
     if (window.location.hash.indexOf('news-item') == 1) { // not 0 because # is first character of window.location.hash
         // it's at the start
     }
     else if (window.location.hash.indexOf('news-item') != -1) {
         // it's there, but not at the start
     }
     else {
         // not there
     }
 }
```

Comment: it will be `window.location.hash.indexOf('news-item') == 1`, # will be on index 0

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
var matches = hash.match(/^#news-item-([0-9]+)$/);
if (matches) {
    var number = matches[1];
    // Rest of your code
}
```